# display multiple rows from foreach result using json_encode

Tags: php, ajax, json

I am working on a comment system, and I am trying to build a function that queries and displays 10 newest comments from database using ajax.

The problem I am having is that, I just can't figure out how to display **multiple** rows using **ajax** and **json_encode**.

When I display multiple rows with php, I use `.=`, which is so simple, but with ajax and json_encode, I can only display a single result with my knowledge so far.

Below is the pure PHP version of my code to display multiple rows

```
public function display_comment(){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM 'comment' WHERE 'user_id' = $user_id ORDER BY 'save_time' DESC LIMIT 10";
    $result = $database->query($query);

    foreach($result as $row){
        $user_id = $row['user_id'];
        $user_name = $row['user_name'];
        $comment = $row['comment'];

        $all_comments .= '<div id="' . $user_id . '"><span>' . $user_name . '</span><span>' . $comment . '</span></div>';
    }
}
```

Using ajax and json_encode, this is how I return a single result

```
public function display_comment(){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM 'comment' WHERE 'user_id' = $user_id ORDER BY 'save_time' DESC LIMIT 10";
    $result = $database->query($query);

    foreach($result as $row){
        $user_id = $row['user_id'];
        $user_name = $row['user_name'];
        $comment = $row['comment'];

        $json_array = array("user_id" => $user_id, "user_name" => $user_name, "comment" => $comment);
        header('Content-type:application/json');
        exit(json_encode($json_array)); // I am using exit instead of echo, because somehow if I use echo, it returns entire html page. 
    }
}
```

jQuery part

```
$(document).on("click","#view_comment",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#view_comment").text("loading..");
    var view_comment = $(this).val(); // Don't worry about this

    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        data:{"view_comment":view_comment},
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(data){
            $('#ajax_comment').html('<div id="' + data.user_id + '"><span>' + data.user_name + '</span><span>' + data.comment + '</span></div>');
        },
        error:function(data){
            // Error code
        }
    });
});
```

How should I change my code in order to display multiple rows using json_encode?

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why you're only able to view a single row is because you're existing the script after the first iteration of the `while()` loop:

```
exit(json_encode($json_array));
```

Change the php to:

```
public function display_comment(){
  $query = "SELECT * FROM 'comment' WHERE 'user_id' = $user_id ORDER BY 'save_time' DESC LIMIT 10";
  $result = $database->query($query);
  $results = array();
  foreach($result as $row){
    $user_id = $row['user_id'];
    $user_name = $row['user_name'];
    $comment = $row['comment'];

    $results[] = array("user_id" => $user_id, "user_name" => $user_name, "comment" => $comment);

  }
  header('Content-type:application/json');
  exit(json_encode($results)); 
}
```

Javascript

```
$(document).on("click","#view_comment",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#view_comment").text("loading..");
    var view_comment = $(this).val(); // Don't worry about this

    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        data:{"view_comment":view_comment},
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(data){
            var html = '', comment;
            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                comment = data[i];
                html += '<div id="' + comment.user_id + '"><span>' + comment.user_name + '</span><span>' + comment.comment + '</span></div>'
            }
            $('#ajax_comment').html(html);
        },
        error:function(data){
            // Error code
        }
    });
});
```